Knee seems to fall behind the pedal axle even the saddle is in most upfront position
I am trying to find an ideal saddle height and fore/aft position on my MTB but the tip of my knee does not align with the pedal axle. It falls behind the pedal axle even though I set the saddle in most upfront position. What is the problem here?

Whether your knee aligns with the pedal axle or not is completely irrelevant. Different kinds of bikes will have different seat tube angles and the crank length also matters.
The more upright sitting position the bike is made for, the more likely you are to end up with you knee behind the pedal axle. But it is not completely general.
The seat fore/aft position should be determined based on trying how stable you sit and whether you are able to lift your back when pedaling and whether you slide forward or backward or not. Check some bike fit videos or articles for more or even contact a bike fitter.

The bike is a 26" hardtail MTB. It is a bit small for my size. I am around 175 cm tall. Seat tube is 44.5 cm and (effective) top tube 54.5 cm. I think my knees fall behind the pedal axle as I raise the saddle too much. Actually it's within the limits of the seat tube.

@Ender For a fixed seat tube angle the frame size should not really matter at all for the knee vs pedal position. Set up your bike using other more important crieteria. Maybe it will fit, maybe not. But the knee to axle position is unimportant.
